# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I am trying to build a HelloWorld android app using cordova.
I am following footsteps mentioned on follwoing page
http://javaonlineguide.net/2015/06/apache-cordova-hello-world-program-for-android-platform-in-eclipse-example.html

I've been browsing the issue and I'm pretty sure I'm not having the same issues as mentioned. Both of my activities are declared in the AndroidManifest and the intent filter is there. I tried replacing in my Manifest com.example.main.MainActivity by .MainActivity but still no luck. I'm using Eclipse IDE
In Java build path-> Order and Export 
Android Private Libraries is checked

I have tried building and cleaning project again and again. I even tried restarting Eclipse.

[Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Lrb.png)

Here is Logcat:

```
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): Process: com.example.main, PID: 1133
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.main/com.example.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.main.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.main-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.main-1, /system/lib]]
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.main.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.main-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.main-1, /system/lib]]
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-14 06:07:36.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.main"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.0.1" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

</manifest>
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.main;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are declare this way

```
  <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
```

just put `.` to `MainActivity` like this

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: Hi Ironman, Thanks for your response. I tried that. But error still persists

Comment: yes. I did that. Tried cleaning and building project after suggested change.

Answer (score 5):

I have stopped the Instant run from Android studio and its working.

File->Setting->Build->Instant Run->Disble checkbox of Enable instant run to hotswap code/resource changes

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, in your activity tag, add a '.' before MainActivity

```
`android:name=".MainActivity"`
```

You can consider `android.name` as a continuation of `package` name. So, without the dot it would be `com.example.mainMainActivity` which is wrong. The correct structure would be `com.example.main.MainActivity`

Comment: Clean and build. Let me know what the error is after that.

Comment: Tried cleaning and building. I am getting same error.

Comment: 07-14 06:54:53.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.main/com.example.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.main.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.main-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.main-2, /system/lib]]

Comment: Are you sure MainActivity is not inside a sub-package in com.example.main. If so, the name should be android:name=".<subPackkageName>.MainActivity"

Comment: yes I am pretty sure MainActivity is not inside a sub-package. I tried uploading pic of Project Explorer but I don't have those authorities yet. Sorry for that.

Comment: here is pic of Project Explorer : http://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Lrb.png. MainActivity class is in package com.example.main

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was build application using Cordova.

I was building project in Eclipse but with that I also needed to build project using command :

```
E:\Software\Demo\VMSapp>cordova build
```

This command updates APK file.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my device and it just worked!

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, do this if the name is already `'.MainActivity'` and still showing error.

Eg :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.pakgename.MainActivity"
            ...
</activity>
```